# Template specialization with const: "ambiguous template instantiation" error on gcc but not clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17, template-specialization

The below code compiles on clang (I tried 7 and 8), but not gcc (7, 8, or 9), all using `--std=c++17`. With gcc I get an `ambiguous template instantiation` error, as you can see here: https://godbolt.org/z/69Bomq.

I can fix it for gcc by uncommenting `#define FIX_GCC`. If I change `first_type<C>` and `first_type<const C>` to `C` and `const C` in the specializations of `traits<Map<...>>`, it also compiles, but in my real code if have some `enable_if_t<...>` to narrow down the specialization there.

Is gcc wrong here? Or am I doing something wrong that clang happens to accept?

**Update:** Removing one layer of templates, i.e. `Map`, in the specialization also makes GCC happy here even with the template alias `first_type`, see https://godbolt.org/z/90kGEP.

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:36:38: error: ambiguous template instantiation for 'struct traits<Map<const Foo> >'
   36 |   std::cout << traits<Map<const Foo>>::N << std::endl;
      |                                      ^~
<source>:24:8: note: candidates are: 'template<class C> struct traits<Map<first_type<C> > > [with C = const Foo]'
   24 | struct traits<Map<first_type<C>>> {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:30:8: note:                 'template<class C> struct traits<Map<first_type<const C> > > [with C = Foo]'
   30 | struct traits<Map<first_type<const C>>> {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:36:40: error: incomplete type 'traits<Map<const Foo> >' used in nested name specifier
   36 |   std::cout << traits<Map<const Foo>>::N << std::endl;
      |                                        ^
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class...>
using first_type = T;

class Foo {};

template <class C>
class Map {};

template <class C>
struct traits {};

//#define FIX_GCC

#ifdef FIX_GCC
template <typename C>
struct traits<Map<first_type<C, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const_v<C>>>>> {
  static constexpr int N = 2;
};
#else
template <typename C>
struct traits<Map<first_type<C>>> {
  static constexpr int N = 2;
};
#endif

template <typename C>
struct traits<Map<first_type<const C>>> {
  static constexpr int N = 3;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << traits<Map<Foo>>::N << std::endl;
  std::cout << traits<Map<const Foo>>::N << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, but I'm not entirely certain. gcc has no problem if you change the `first_type` aliases to just `C` and `const C` - but a use of an alias template is supposed to be equivalent to immediately substituting the alias definition, except that any unused template arguments still need to have template parameters substituted and checked for semantics for SFINAE effects.

Comment: If you want simplify a little your example, you can define `first_type` as `template <class T, class...> using first_type = T;`, so you can avoid the `void` in definition of `traits` specializations (maintaining the `std::enable_if_t` for the fix). Anyway, I bet my 2 cents in a g++ bug: the `N=3` version should be more specialized than the `N = 2` version. But I'm not a language layer so I'll wait for experts.

Comment: Thanks, I applied the simplification. I also tested with removing `Map`, which make GCC happy as well, see the update above. I'll wait a little bit if someone else has some idea and maybe else file a bug report with gcc.

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90679